# "standard" single-command alternative for `mkdir -p BASE/a/b/c && cp -a -t BASE/a/b/c /a/b/c/d`?

Tags: command-line, file-copy

The sequence of commands

```
mkdir -p BASE/a/b/c && cp -a --target-directory=BASE/a/b/c /a/b/c/d
```

creates a subdirectory `a/b/c` under `BASE`, and then copies the directory tree at `/a/b/c/d` to `BASE/a/b/c`.

One problem with it is that it entails a lot of repetition, which invites errors.

I can roll a shell function that encapsulates this operation; for example, here's a sketch of it without any error checking/handling:

```
copytwig () {
    local source=$1
    local base=$2
    local target=$base/$( dirname $source )

    mkdir -p $target && cp -a --target-directory=$target $source
}
```

...but I was wondering if this could already be done with a "standard" Unix utility (where I'm using "standard" as shorthand for "likely to be found in a Unix system, or at least likely to be found in a Linux system").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With  `pax` (a mandatory POSIX utility, though not installed by default in some GNU/Linux distributions yet):

```
pax -s':^:BASE/:' -pe -rw /a/b/c/d .
```

(note that neither `--target-directory` nor `-a` are standard `cp` options. Those are GNU extensions).

Note that with `-pe` (similar to GNU's `-a`), `pax` will try and copy the metadata (times, owner, permissions...) of the directory components as well (while `BASE`'s metadata will be as if created with `mkdir BASE`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--parents` switch for `cp` to preserve the directory structure.

```
mkdir BASE && cp --parents -a --target-directory=BASE /a/b/c/d
```

Edit: sorry, you asked for a Unix solution, but this seems to be Linux only. :(